# Gradient and Laplacian in integral.

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

Let $u,v,f$ be functions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with compact support in a domain $U$, this formula
$$\int_{U} f(x) (Du \cdot Dv) dx = \int_{U} f(x)(u D(Dv)) dx = \int_{U} f(x) u(x) \Delta v(x) dx$$

is true?

In simples words, Can I exchange the gradients?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ have compact support.

Comment: Yeah! I understand, but my question is when $f,u$ and $v$ have compact support, because If I apply Integration by parts the boundary terms vanish in $\partial U$

Comment: When you integrated by parts, why did you not differentiate $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean in the middle integral but yes this is Green's first Identity with no boundary term: [Green's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities)